# NHibernate unnecessary join in many to many using count on child collection

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am developing a bookmark system in ASP.NET MVC and I use NHibernate to query the database.

I have a many to many relationship:

- bookmark can have many tags
- A tag can have many bookmarks

Models:

```
public class Bookmark
{
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual string Link { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Bookmark> Bookmarks { get; set; }
}
```

I need a list with tags and for each tag I need its total bookmarks. Works fine with this:

```
public IList<TagWithBookmarkCount> GetTagsWithBookmarkCount(string username)
{
    ICriteria criteriaQuery = SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession()
            .CreateCriteria(typeof(Tag))
            .CreateAlias("User", "u")
            .CreateAlias("Bookmarks", "b")
            .SetProjection (Projections.ProjectionList()
            .Add (Projections.GroupProperty("Title"), "Title")
            .Add (Projections.GroupProperty("Description"), "Description")
            .Add (Projections.Count("Bookmarks"), "BookmarkCount"))
            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("u.Username", username));

    criteriaQuery.SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean (typeof(TagWithBookmarkCount)));

    IList<TagWithBookmarkCount> tags = criteriaQuery.List<TagWithBookmarkCount>();

    return tags;
}
```

This produces the following query:

```
SELECT this_.Title       as y0_,
   this_.Description as y1_,
   count(this_.Id)   as y2_
FROM   Tags this_
   inner join TagsBookmarks bookmarks4_
     on this_.Id = bookmarks4_.TagId
   inner join Bookmarks b2_
     on bookmarks4_.BookmarkId = b2_.Id
   inner join Users u1_
     on this_.UserId = u1_.Id
WHERE  u1_.Username = 'Mr.nuub' /* @p0 */
GROUP  BY this_.Title,
      this_.Description
```

The inner join on Bookmarks is not necessary. I use Fluent mapping with HasManyToMany on both Bookmark and Tag. I don't think mapping the junction table is best practice. Can I avoid this join without mapping the junction table? Or should I not worry about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case the inner join to `Bookmarks` is unnecessary.

However, it would be wrong of NHibernate to make that assumption. NHibernate does not know that there is a foreign key constraint from `TagsBookmarks.BookmarkId` to `Bookmarks`. For all it knows, this column could be linking to any one of a selection of tables.

Fortunately, your database DOES know that there is a foreign key constraint, and should optimize this join right out of your query. Are you using SQL Server? Try manually typing the two queries, one with the inner join to Bookmarks, and one without the inner join. Look at the execution plans, and you will see they are identical.

Therefore your latter conclusion is correct - you can happily not worry about it.

---

As an aside, it really should be a `LEFT OUTER` join to `TagsBookmarks`. Otherwise your results will omit tags that have zero bookmarks.

```
        .CreateAlias("Bookmarks", "b", JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
```